# Android - How to send data from main activity to loaded fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, implementation

I want to have a `function` that is constant between all my `Fragments` placed in `MainActivity`. I am not sure how to pass the data to the `active` `Fragment` since the `Fragment` will be unaware of the function being run.

I have tried creating an `interface` in the `MainActivity` and have the `Fragment` `implement` the `MainActivity.OnDataPass`. but not sure how to initiate the interface in the `MainActivity` I keep getting a `NullPointerException`.

In my main activity:

```
public class Mainactivity extends FragmentActivity{
    OnDataPass dataPasser;
    BroadcastReceiver receiver;
    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String str = intent.getStringExtra("data");
                dataPasser.onDataPass(str);
            }
        };
    }

    public interface OnDataPass {
        public void onDataPass(String data);
    }
}
```

In my Fragment

```
public class Storage extends Fragment implements Mainactivity.OnDataPass{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        mrootview = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.storage, container, false);
        return mrootview;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataPass(String data) {
        Log.v(TAG, data);

    }
}
```

am I even on the right track or is there a better way to send data to the fragment?

Comment: When do you want to send the data? You should either pass it through the `args` when you create the fragment, or use the `FragmentManager` to get an instance and yes you can use your interface, feels your questions is missing the vital piece of code where you attempt to call `onDataPass`

Comment: @Blundell do you know syntax I would use to set dataPasser dynamically?  or how I would set it just for storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pretty far already:

```
public class Mainactivity extends FragmentActivity{
    OnDataPass dataPasser;

    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //When you create your fragment, keep a reference of it in the dataPasser variable
        dataPasser = /* your storage fragment class or any other fragment that implements onDataPass*/
        ......
        receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
              @Override
               public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    String str = intent.getStringExtra("data");
                    dataPasser.onDataPass(str);
               }
        };
    }       


    public interface OnDataPass {
        public void onDataPass(String data);
    }
}
```

Comment: it is where dataPaser = I am confused. I do not know what fragment will be loaded, it could be one of many

Comment: Where is determined what fragment gets loaded, or what fragment is needed?

Comment: I can set dataPasser when the fragment is loaded, just not sure on the syntax to set dataPasser like `dataPasser = ((Storage)getActivity());`

Comment: `dataPasser = (OnDataPass) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MyFragTag");` there are a few variatons of this, just google `FragmentManager`